# In Solovay's proof that generic extension is also generic over any intermediate model, why is transfinite induction required?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm trying to understand the proof of Lemma 4.4 in Solovay's famous paper "A Model of Set-Theory in Which Every Set of Reals is Lebesgue Measurable".
The lemma is slightly more complicated, but it basically says that if $M[G]$ is some generic extension (with $G\subseteq P_1$), and $M[s]$ is a subextension, then there is a subset $\Sigma\subseteq P_1$ (in $M[s]$) s.t $G$ is generic with respect to it (and hence $M[G]=M[s][G]$ is a generic extension of $M[s]$).

To build $\Sigma$, he builds some increasing sets of "bad element" to remove from $P_1$.
[image]
I don't understand why we need more than 1 step. If we take an union of dense subsets over each element of a dense subset, we get a dense subset, right? So all of the elements should be in $A_1$.

More formally, suppose that $p\in A_2$. Then by definition there is a dense subset $X$ s.t for every $q\ge p$ in $X$, $q\in A_1$.
but for each $q\in A_1$ there is a dense subset $Y_q$ s.t. for every $r\ge q$ in $Y_q$, $r\in A_0$.

Hence, if we take the dense subset $D=\left\{r: \ if\ r\ge p\ then\ there\ is\ q\in X\ s.t\ r\ge q\ge p\ and\ r\in Y_q\right\}$ , we can get that $p\in A_1$.

What am I missing?

Comment: One quick problem with your reasoning: Why should we be able to make the choice of $Y_q$ for each $q$ in $M$? For $D$ to be in $M$ we would need the map $q \mapsto Y_q$ to be also in $M$.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan I'm assuming ZFC, so if there is such $Y_q$ for any $q$, I can get such a map.
(Also, the construction is over $M[s]$, since $A_0$ is depending on $s$)

Comment: @asaeir Yes, you can get it in $M[s]$. But why in $M$? In (2) they write "for every dense subset [...] lying in $M$". Note that $A_0$ is not necessarily in $M$.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan Thanks. I missed that we only remove $p$ if that dense subset over it is in $M$.
(I still don't see how that requirements is needed later in the proof, but that's another issue...)